# how to iterate through list of items and extract img using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

im trying to scrape data from a website using Selenium. The website contains a list of items, each with various attributes with specific data-aut-id attributes. I'm using a loop to iterate through the items and extract the data, but I'm encountering issues with the 'src' attribute stopping after 11 loops.

here is my code, i hope someone will able to help with my problem

```
url = "https://www.olx.co.id/mobil_c86"
ul_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul[data-aut-id='itemsList']")
time.sleep(1)
li_elements = ul_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-aut-id='itemBox']")

for li_element in li_elements:
    time.sleep(3)
    try:
        # Extract link
        link_element = li_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a")
        link = link_element.get_attribute("href")
        links.append(link)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        links.append(None)

    try:
        # Extract image source
        image_element = li_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img")
        image_source = image_element.get_attribute("src")
        image_sources.append(image_source)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        image_sources.append(None)
 
        # Extract price,year,title,location
```

Answer (score 1):

Bottom part of elements from your list are loaded async, so you need to init their loading by perform some user actions, like scrolling, etc.

For example, you can scroll to load more button via `ActionChains` and only then perform actions that gets src attributes of images - at least that would init render logic of the bottom list items.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
links = []
image_sources = []
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
url = "https://www.olx.co.id/mobil_c86"
driver.get(url)
load_more = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[data-aut-id=btnLoadMore]')))
ActionChains(driver).scroll_to_element(load_more).perform()
ul_element = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "ul[data-aut-id='itemsList']")
li_elements = ul_element.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li[data-aut-id='itemBox']")

for li_element in li_elements:
        link_element = li_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a")
        link = link_element.get_attribute("href")
        links.append(link)

        image_element = li_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img")
        image_source = image_element.get_attribute("src")
        image_sources.append(image_source)
        print(image_source)
```

Comment: weird i got an error 'ActionChains' object has no attribute 'scroll_to_element'

Comment: Can you install latest version of Selenium? https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/actions_api/wheel/

Answer (score 0):

Each li elements has **_1DNjI**  class name so you can gather information like that.  Not sure if u ever tried that.

```
link_elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"._1DNjI a")
```

for image you can use that.

```
img_elements = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"._1DNjI a ._3UrC5 img")
```

Comment: i tried to change it, but somehow it doesnt fix the issue with the 'src' attribute stopping after 11 loops.

Comment: Maybe u can use bs4 to get all the information and add it. Bs4 is better than Selenium for gathering information. I usually use selenium for automation and gather data with bs4.

Comment: perhaps, but i need selenium automation to change the dynamic page (load more button) + the location, not sure i will be able to use that in bs4

Comment: Yeap you can do that. It will be like go page gather information and change page.

Comment: You will only need to use bs4 instead of gathering information part. You'll keep same other parts. I hope it can help to your project.

Comment: is that so? even the load button doesnt direct to other page? maybe il check it later